# css .not(this) element according to it's index

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create an accordion slider.
So far I've managed to:

1. initiate the first position of each slide by dividing the slider width by the number of sliders.
2. each click on a slide moves it to a position equals 5% * the index value of the current slide (eg 0x5% of 1st slide, 1x5% of 2nd slide, 2x5% of 3rd slide and so on).

here's the code so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $(".slides li").each(function(initial) {
    var sliderwidth = $(".slides").width(); //entire slider width
    var slideindex = $(".slides li").length; //how many slides are in a slider
    var firstpos = sliderwidth / slideindex; //divided entire width by number of slides (1000/4 in this case, equals 250)
    initial = initial * firstpos; //each slides's initial position is incremented by 250, making the slides position 0, 250px, 500px, 750px
    $(this).css("left", initial); //css left with numbers above
  });

  $(".slides li").click(function() {
    var moveindex = $(".slides li").index(this); //the index value of the clicked slide (eg. 0, 1, 2 or 3)
    var movethis = parseInt(moveindex, 10) * 5; //multiply index value of current slide by 5 (as we want each slide to position itself on click 5% to the left)
    $(this).css("left", movethis + "%"); //css left with numbers above

  });

});
```

Now I'm trying to get OTHER slides (not the current clicked slide) to move according to their relative index value. For example:

clicking slide #4 would move slide 1 to 0x5%, slide 2 to 1x5%, slide 3 to 2x5%.

But I can't find a way to

```
$(".slides li").not(this).index();
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `index` you are able to get the index for the passed element in the result set you call `index` on.

So you want to iterat over all `li` that are not `this` and check what `index` this `li` has in the list of all `li`:

```
var listOfAllLi = $(".slides li")
var listWithoutThis = listOfAllLi.not(this)

listWithoutThis.each(function(_, element) {
  var indexOfElement = listOfAllLi.index(element)
  console.log(indexOfElement)
})
```

Comment: thanks! So how would I go about inserting this into a click function?

Comment: @IdoAngel-Bohadana this will already work in the click function. You for sure need to replace the `console.log(listOfAllLi.index(element))` with code that does somethign usefull with the `element`.

Comment: tried this:

var listOfAllLi = $(".slides li")
var listWithoutThis = listOfAllLi.not(this)

listWithoutThis.each(function(idx, element) {
  idx=idx*5;
  $(".slides li").not(this).css("left", idx+"%");
})

but didn't work... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @IdoAngel-Bohadana `element` is the element you want to move and `listOfAllLi.index(element)` is the index of that element. So you do you want to use `$(".slides li").not(this)` again, if you already have `element`?

Comment: ah! so something like this:

listWithoutThis.each(function(idx, element) {
  var previndex = listOfAllLi.index(element)*5
  $(element).css("left", previndex+"%");
})

Comment: so i have this which works great:
`var listOfAllLi = $(".slides li")
var listWithoutThis = listOfAllLi.not(this)
listWithoutThis.each(function(idx, element) {
  var previndex = listWithoutThis.index(element)*5;
  $(element).css("left", previndex+"%");
})`
but i want to apply it only to the previous children of the clicked li (because next children should be treated differently). I tried:
`$(element).prevAll().css("left", previndex+"%");`
but that didn't work.

Comment: @IdoAngel-Bohadana The comment section is for clearificatin about the question or the answer. If you have a new follow up question then you should create a new one.

Comment: thanks, you're right - sorry :) got this figured out!